# IntelliJ Alt+Enter dialog does not list "Create Test"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I press `Alt + Enter` on a class name in IntelliJ (version 2017.2 on a Windows 10 machine) the `Create Test`option is not listed. What can I do to get it there?

My window looks like
[image]

And i was expecting something like 
[image]
It comes from the [IntelliJ help page for creating tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-tests.html).

Is there an option to add the `Create Test` dialog to the menu?

Comment: What class gave the context menu in the second screenshot? It looks like it has code whereas the first example does not.

Comment: The second image comes from the IntelliJ help page. I've added the link in the question. Also, when I add a method, the option does not appear.

Comment: Did you add a static or non-static method? Did you try both?

Comment: Yes, I did try it.

Comment: Do you have the JUnit and TestNG-J plugins disabled by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

Default is `Ctrl + Shift + T`

or you can change it by entering the keymap menu, `Ctrl + Alt + S` to open up the settings, then keymap...

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Panayiotis Poularakis, but this is more a workaround than a solution. Cause of that, I will not accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To enable this option, go to IDEA Settings -> Editor -> Intentions -> Java -> Declaration and select checkbox Create Test. Search in top left corner can help.

[image: IntellJ IDEA setting create test]

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a test for JUnit in IntelliJ kindly follow these steps:

1. Create a new Project using your favorite framework (e.g. Maven)
2. Create a basic test class
3. Next, right-click on your Class and choose “Generate”  to generate a Test Class
   [image]

**Ensure you check the class function/member checkbox then click OK**